# best way to aggregate the results of history command

Tags: bash, aggregate

I get my history commands by `history`

```
2  cmake
3  cd /Applications/
4  open Cmake.app
5  open Cmake.app
6  sudo bash
7  Cmake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui
8  sudo "/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui" --install
9  cmake
10  which cmake
```

And I want to aggregate the results to something like:

```
cmake 2
open Cmake.app 2
cd /Applications/ 1
...
```

What command line should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Please try it:

```
$ history | cut -d ' ' -f 4- | sort | uniq -c | awk '{for (i = 2; i < NF; i++) {printf("%s ", $i)} print $NF " " $1}'
```